# How to automatically read multiple test cases in Python, where the test cases are stored in a notepad file?

Tags: python

I have written a Python code that takes the number of test cases as user input and then takes 3 user inputs in the same line and performs some action

I have 100 test cases and I don't want to enter the input everytime, rather I want to read the test cases that I have in a notepad file and perform the actions that is written in the code

Here is the sample code

```
tests=int(input())
for test in range(tests):
  bal, cost, wrap = map(int, input().split())
  choc=bal//cost
  if(choc<wrap):
    print(int(choc))
  elif(choc>=wrap):
    in_choc=choc
    #rem=choc%wrap
    while(choc%wrap!=0):
      choc+=1
    extra=choc/wrap
    #print(choc, wrap, extra)
    print(int(in_choc+extra))
```

here is the input(test cases that I have stored int the notepad file)

> 16809 123 11668
>
> 20373 18211 10188
>
> 92512 413 33040
>
> 2339 4 1337
>
> 96741 945 77194

the next lines contain all the test cases

Comment: What exactly is... the question?

Comment: If the input is exactly what you included into the question, and you have problems reading the lines then the empty lines between the data lines may be the cause.

Comment: @RonnyEfronny if I have 100 test cases stored in a notepad file and I do not want to manually enter the test cases rather I automatically want to read the input from the notepad file

Comment: @RonnyEfronny Now, I think he simply wants to read from a file input. `f = open("testfile.txt", "r")` and `f.readline()`. Sorry I'm no python programmer, so I'd like to not give an answer.

Comment: Now you removed the "count of lines"  number from the beginning of the file. That's no good Idea. Then you also have to check if there are lines left to read.

Comment: You are not testing anything. You seem to be evaluating a set of inputs, each with three values, in a loop. In order to call this testing, you should have at least have a column of known values to test the result of the inputs with.

Answer (score 3):

Use this code for multiline testcases without explicitly providing number of testcases from a text file:

```
f = open("file.txt", "r")
while(True):
  line_input=f.readline()
  if(line_input):
    bal, cost, wrap = map(int, line_input.split())
    choc=bal//cost
    if(choc<wrap):
      print(int(choc))
    elif(choc>=wrap):
      in_choc=choc
      #rem=choc%wrap
      while(choc%wrap!=0):
        choc+=1
      extra=choc/wrap
      #print(choc, wrap, extra)
      print(int(in_choc+extra))
  else:
    break
f.close()
```

Comment: If the issue (which was never actually stated) was reading the file then this is the solution.

Answer (score 1):

## Solution

Your code does some redundant steps, which if you optimize, you could write it as follows.

```py
# concise version of your evaluator function
def evaluate(bal, cost, wrap):
    choc = bal//cost
    result = None
    if (choc < wrap):
        result = int(choc)
    else:
        result = int(choc + (choc//wrap) + 1)
    return result

# testing function
def test_logic(bal, cost, wrap, expected):    
    assert evaluate(bal, cost, wrap) == expected

# evaluate inputs
# expected values: [136, 1, 2403, 584, 102] for dummy data
[evaluate(bal, cost, wrap) for (bal, cost, wrap) in inputs]
```

**Output**:

```
[136, 1, 2403, 584, 102]
```

### Dummy Data

```py
inputs = [
    (16809, 123, 11668, ), 
    (20373, 18211, 10188, ), 
    (992512, 413, 33040, ), 
    (2339, 4, 1337, ), 
    (96741, 945, 77194, ), 
]
```